# Pointer in nested structure

Tags: c, pointers, nested, structure

How do we use the pointers in nested structure?

I created two structure in the code given below, how can I access the elements of `st_no`?
Explain about nested structure thoroughly .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   char st_no[22];
   int no;
}address;

typedef struct
{
  char name[15];
  int mark;
  address addr;
}student;

int main (void)
{
 student *selva;

strcpy(selva->name, "ajay");
strcpy(selva->addr.st_no,"3rd st");
printf("%s",selva->name);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will segfault as `selva` is an uninitialised pointer. Perhaps remove the pointer and use it as a local object? Also add `#include <string.h>` for your `strcpy` function.

Answer (score 3):

You only have a pointer to a student, not an actual student.  To allocate dynamically you need:

```
student * selva = malloc(sizeof(student))  // be sure to free this later
```

Then you can do:

```
strcpy(selva->addr.st_no, "3rd st")
```

Or if you don't need to do it dynamically, you can create the variable on the stack like so:

```
student selva
```

Then to copy into `st_no` you can:

```
strcpy(selva.addr.st_no, "3rd st")
```

Comment: Probably also worth pointing out that if it's just for the sake of using pointers, OP can just point a pointer to a struct on the stack and then carry on with the original code. OP won't have to worry about freeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below

```
student *selva;
selva = malloc(sizeof(student));
strcpy(selva->name, "ajay");
strcpy(selva->addr.st_no,"3rd st");
```